# db2: sql select query giving an abend

Tags: sql, db2, zos

while i was trying to retrieve data  from a table of db2 supplied sample database

```
select * from DSN8910.EMP;
```

its giving an error

> Aend 0C4000 hex

similar error occurred on spufi as well as QMF

but if I retrieve only empno its giving results

```
select empno from DSN8A10.EMP
```

table discription

```
CREATE TABLE DSN8A10.EMP
      (EMPNO     CHAR(6)                          NOT NULL,
       FIRSTNME  VARCHAR(12)                      NOT NULL,
       MIDINIT   CHAR(1)                          NOT NULL,
       LASTNAME  VARCHAR(15)                      NOT NULL,
       WORKDEPT  CHAR(3)                                  ,
       PHONENO   CHAR(4)         CONSTRAINT NUMBER CHECK
                 (PHONENO >= '0000' AND
                  PHONENO <= '9999')                      ,
       HIREDATE  DATE                                     ,
       JOB       CHAR(8)                                  ,
       EDLEVEL   SMALLINT                                 ,
       SEX       CHAR(1)                                  ,
       BIRTHDATE DATE                                     ,
       SALARY    DECIMAL(9,2)                             ,
       BONUS     DECIMAL(9,2)                             ,
       COMM      DECIMAL(9,2)                             ,
       PRIMARY KEY (EMPNO)                                ,
       FOREIGN KEY RED (WORKDEPT) REFERENCES DSN8A10.DEPT
                 ON DELETE SET NULL                       )
  EDITPROC  DSN8EAE1
  IN DSN8D10A.DSN8S10E
  CCSID EBCDIC;
```

Comment: You [may need a PTF](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI43844#more)?

Comment: not known  muck abot PTF ,,, it might be some sort of security permision.

Comment: but able to access rest of the tables of same database and aslo able to access empno of emp table